# ASP.net: Weird web user control problem

Tags: asp.net

This is weird. I declare a web user control on a asp.net web page like so

```
print("<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/blah.ascx" TagName="blahCtrl" TagPrefix="cc" %>");
```

I don't have problem with it until today in the code behind where it give me name blah is not declared error. does anyone know what cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Try registering it on the .aspx source page not the .aspx.cs page.